# What does "scalability" mean?

Tags: scalability

I read many articles comparing programming languages.

There is a word that comes often: *scalability*. I actually tried to look for a simple and clear explanation, but haven't found anything.

Can you explain what the *scalability* term means?

Comment: Take a look at the hover for the scalability tag... That's a good start! Google it, as well. There are a billion resources out there that explain it fully and easily... such as http://shiflett.org/blog/2003/oct/what-is-scalability

Comment: In the figures in @king14nyr's link, the O(c^n), O(n), and O(log(n)), are all Big-O notation. As you can see with large sets of data (n records), programs that have O(log(n)) pattern will run very well, whereas O(c^n) would perform VERY poorly. Those are the two extremes.

Comment: There is a language whose name stems from "scalability" - Scala. What it means you can find out here: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/130340/92672

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Scalability is the ability of a program to scale. For example, if you can do something on a small database (say less than 1000 records), a program that is highly scalable would work well on a small set as well as working well on a large set (say millions, or billions of records).

Like gap said, it would have a linear growth of resource requirements. Look up Big-O notation for more details about how programs can require more computation the larger the data input gets. Something parabolic like Big-O(x^2) is far less efficient with large x inputs than something linear like Big-O(x).

Comment: This is actually wrong.for one linear scalability would have linear growth. you can still be scalable in non linear ways (naturally to a limit). Secondly the scalability is gained/shown by changing hardware. if I have a huge setup and I first run it with 1 TPS while it can actually handle 100 TPS - running it on 100TPS is not scaling it. If the load can increase to 10KTPS by changing the HW then it is scalable

Comment: In the context of the OP question, I was describing the scalability of software algorithms. This context is typical in college coursework. When comparing the scalability of two potential algorithms, one with linear resource requirements is going to be highly scalable in comparison to one with parabolic resource requirements.

Comment: I get what scalability is particular in software algorithms. But what is scalability in a programming language?

Comment: @jafar, the same principal applies to programming languages. A programming language is scalable when you can write small or large programs in it with a linear growth in resource requirements. This all depends on the syntax and semantics of the language. More discussion and comparison of different languages (albeit a few years out of date) are here: http://users.cms.caltech.edu/~mvanier/hacking/rants/scalable_computer_programming_languages.html

Answer (score 33):

Scalability is the trait where a software solution can handle increased loads of work. This can be larger data-sets, higher request rates, combination of size and velocity etc.

When talking about systems scalability, we usually differentiate between

- "Scale up" - the ability to grow by using stronger hardware
- "Scale out"- the ability to grow by adding more hardware

A solution that can scale out can usually grow to lager loads in a more cost effective way. An important thing to know here is [Amdahl's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law) that states that the ability to scale out is limited by the sequential part of the software

Answer (score 14):

Already great answers here, just wanted to add few things here.

Scalability can be achieved in 2 ways:

1. Vertical - In this way, you add more hardware like more RAM, processor or more nodes. You also introduce load balancer, which will help in routing the incoming calls to various servers based on the routing algorithm used. The application is now able to handle more load as load is being shared across the servers.
2. Horizontal - In horizontal scaling, you architect/design the application in such a way that it can behave well in case of more parallel traffic. You check how you are managing the memory, sessions , cache & state etc. If you are using the session to maintain the user information, under heavy load single server could be more busy managing the servers, so in this case you can check possibility of going stateless. It can also respond to incoming requests from same user in parallel instead serial replies which happens if sessions are being used.

Answer (score 11):

My understanding is it means that a **linear increase in output requested** only demands a **linear increase in resources**.